# subquery does not work correctly

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

i have used below sub-query for returning maximum data of each (Document Number) from my query but it returns just one record while i have many records.

```
 SELECT tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number]
      , tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-   NO]
      , tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date]

FROM tblTransmittals 
INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo 
  ON tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-  NO] = tbltransmittalNo.[Int-Tr-NO]
WHERE (((tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date])=
        (SELECT Max(A.[Internal-Tr-  Date]) 
         FROM (SELECT tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number]
                    , tbltransmittalNo.   [Internal-Tr-Date]
               FROM tblTransmittals 
               INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo 
                  ON tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-NO] = tbltransmittalNo.[Int-Tr-NO]
              ) AS A 
         WHERE A.[owner Document Number]=[tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number])));
```

i mean if data of query is like below :

```
   Owner Document Number    Int-Tr-NO         Internal-Tr-Date
    doc-0001               tt-0002            10-oct-2016
    doc-0001                tt-0003            12-0ct-2017
    doc-0005                tt-0100            18-sep-2015
```

i would like after using subquery it returns:

```
    Owner Document Number    Int-Tr-NO         Internal-Tr-Date

    doc-0001                tt-0003            12-0ct-2017
    doc-0005                tt-0100            18-sep-2015
```

i tried and checked everything but i do not know why does not work?

Comment: Why is tagged with Access? This sure looks like sql server to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally clear what you want here and I am assuming this is sql server. Think you want something like this.

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT t.[Owner Document Number]
          , t.[Int-Tr-   NO]
          , tn.[Internal-Tr-Date]
          , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by t.[Owner Document Number] order by tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date] desc)
    FROM tblTransmittals t 
    INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo tn ON t.[Int-Tr-  NO] = tn.[Int-Tr-NO]
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: thanks, is it possible answer this question also with using subquery, actually i would like to know what is problem of my code.

Comment: I did do this with a subquery.

Comment: I think he don't know what you need exactly.

Comment: The main problem with your attempt is that the subquery needs to be correlated the way you wrote it and it is not. You will get the same value from the subquery for all rows in the main query. You would need to include a where clause to get the max for each row in the main query.

Comment: i had used where clause but i did not used Aliases correctly, what i modified i add to answer, i hope it should be okey.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number], tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-NO], tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date]

 FROM tblTransmittals INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo ON tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-NO] = tbltransmittalNo.[Int-Tr-NO]

 WHERE (((tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date])=

(SELECT Max([Internal-Tr-Date]) 

FROM (SELECT T.[Owner Document Number], T.[Int-Tr-NO], TN.[Internal-Tr-Date]
FROM tblTransmittals AS T LEFT JOIN tbltransmittalNo AS TN ON T.[Int-Tr-NO]   = TN.[Int-Tr-NO]) AS A 

WHERE A.[owner Document Number]=[tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is totally incorrect as it only returns one row due to the max() on your sub-query:

```
(SELECT Max(A.[Internal-Tr-  Date]) 
    FROM (SELECT tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number], tbltransmittalNo.   [Internal-Tr-Date]
FROM tblTransmittals INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo 
ON tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-NO] = tbltransmittalNo.[Int-Tr-NO]) AS A
WHERE A.[owner Document Number]=[tblTransmittals].[Owner Document Number]);
##this query only returns 1 value
```

In your scenario above, the max() query will return "12-0ct-2017" and your final query will look like this:

SELECT tblTransmittals.[Owner Document Number], tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-   NO], tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date]
    FROM tblTransmittals INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo 
    ON tblTransmittals.[Int-Tr-  NO] = tbltransmittalNo.[Int-Tr-NO]
    WHERE (((tbltransmittalNo.[Internal-Tr-Date])= '20171012'

I'm guessing that you want to return max(date) on each of the [Owner Document Number] and so I would do this:

SELECT A.[Owner Document Number], A.[Int-Tr-   NO], B.[Internal-Tr-Date]
    FROM tblTransmittals as A INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo as B
    ON A.[Int-Tr-  NO] = B.[Int-Tr-NO]
    JOIN
    (SELECT C.[Owner Document Number], max(D.[Internal-Tr-Date])
    FROM tblTransmittals as C INNER JOIN tbltransmittalNo as D
    ON C.[Int-Tr-NO] = D.[Int-Tr-NO] GROUP BY C.[Owner Document Number]) AS E
    ON A.[Owner Document Number] = E.[Owner Document Number]
    and B.[Internal-Tr-Date] = E.[Internal-Tr-Date]

Good luck.

Comment: if you check modified code in my answer that i have used Aliases, you see it is correct and it returns max(date) for each [Owner Document Number]. i have checked with my laptop and it is correct.